# Evaluate $\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}\binom{n}{k}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

I'm interested in finding a nice closed form expression for the sum $\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}\binom{n}{k}$. I've tried using the Binomial Theorem to get 
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}\binom{n}{k}x^k & =\int_0^1\frac{(1+x)^n-1}{x} \, dx\\
&=\int_1^2 (1+u+\cdots+u^{n-1}) \, du
\end{align*}
using the substitution $u=1+x$ but I can't quite to simplify this integral either. I have also not been able to come up with a combinatorial approach, which may not exist since the summation and its terms are in general not integers. Any help in evaluating this sum would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the question, the problem is in *"nice closed form expression"* since
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}\binom{n}{k}x^k=n x \, _3F_2(1,1,1-n;2,2;-x)$$ where appears an hypergoemetric function.

So, let us forget the $x$ and compute for a few values of $n$
$$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}\binom{n}{k}$$
$$\left\{1,\frac{5}{2},\frac{29}{6},\frac{103}{12},\frac{887}{60},\frac{1517}{60},\frac{18239}{420}\right\}$$ which are
$$\left\{1,\frac{5}{2},\frac{29}{6},\frac{206}{24},\frac{1774}{120},\frac{18204}{720},\frac{218868}{5040}\right\}$$ The denominators are clearly $n!$ and the numerators corresponds to sequence [A103213](http://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C5%2C29%2C206&sort=&language=&go=Search) in OEIS.

As you will see in the link is that, for large $n$
$$S_n\approx \frac{2^{n+1}} n$$ It is also given that
$$S_n=-H_n-\Re(B_2(n+1,0))$$ where appear the harmonic number and the real part of the  incomplete beta function.

**Update**

Concerning the asymptotic behavior, it seems that it could be slightly improved using
$$S_n\approx 2^{n+1} n^{\frac{1}{4 n}-1}$$

Comment: It seems like this as simple as it gets and there is no elementary form. The asymptotic approximation is quite helpful though, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to get the same result, and another form as well, without integrals:
$$
\begin{align}
f(n)
&=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k\binom{n}{k}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k\left[\binom{n-1}{k}+\binom{n-1}{k-1}\right]\\
&=f(n-1)+\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k\binom{n-1}{k-1}\\
&=f(n-1)+\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k}\\
&=f(n-1)+\frac{2^n-1}n\\
&=\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{2^k-1}k}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}2^j\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}2^j\sum_{k=j+1}^n\frac1k\\
&=\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}2^j(H_n-H_j)}
\end{align}
$$
However, I don't see a simple closed form.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the best I can (currently?) do.

Continuing on from where you left off, namely
$$S = \sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{1}{k} \binom{n}{k} = \int_1^2 (1 + u + \cdots + u^{n - 1}) \, du, \quad (*)$$
summing the finite geometric series we have
\begin{align*}
S = \sum_{k = 0}^{n- 1} \int_1^2 u^k \, du= \sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1} \frac{2^{k + 1}}{k + 1} - \sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1} \frac{1}{k + 1}= 2 \sum_{k - 0}^{n - 1} \frac{2^k}{k + 1} - H_n.
\end{align*}
Here $H_n$ are the [Harmonic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number).

The sum appearing on the right can be written in the terms of the [Lerch transcendent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lerch_zeta_function) $\Phi(z,s,a)$ as follows.

From the [identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lerch_zeta_function#Identities)
$$\Phi (z,s,a) = z^n \Phi(z,s,a+n) + \sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1} \frac{z^k}{(k + a)^s},$$
setting $a = 1, s = 1$, and $z = 2$, after rearranging, we have
$$\sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1} \frac{2^k}{k + 1} = \Phi(2,1,1) - 2^n \Phi(2,1,n+1).$$
Thus
$$\sum_{k = 0}^n \frac{1}{k} \binom{n}{k} = 2\Phi(2,1,1) - 2^{n + 1} \Phi(2,1,n+1) - H_n.$$
Note each Lerch transcendent appearing in the above expression is complex whose imaginary parts end up canceling out.

($*$) As the number of terms appearing in the integral is finite, the expression is actually in closed formed already. However, I think what you require is an expression that can be written more "compactly" in terms of known (special) functions.

Answer (score 1):

$f(n)=∑ ^n_{k=1}\frac{1}{k} C^n_k $

This is equal to term by term multiplication of following series:

$∑^n_{k=1}  C^n_k =∑^n_{k=0}  C^n_k-1=(1+1)^n-1=2^n-1$

$∑^n_{k=1}\frac{1}{k}= 1+1/2+1/3 + . . . 1/n =H_n  $

⇒ $f(n)=∑ ^n_{k=1}\frac{1}{k} C^n_k =(2^n-1)H_n=∑^n_{k=1}\frac{2^k-1}{k}$

Note that $(2^n-1)$represent$(∑ ^n_{k=1} C^n_k)$ and $(H_n)$ represent$(∑ ^n_{k=1}\frac{1}{k})$ that is $(∑ ^n_{k=1}\frac{1}{k} C^n_k)=∑ ^n_{k=1}\frac{1}{k}\times∑ ^n_{k=1} C^n_k$(term by term multiplication).For example for n=5:

$f(5)=∑ ^5_{k=1}\frac{1}{k} C^5_k$  is not$(2^5-1)(1+1/2+1/3+1/4+1/5)=\frac{4247}{60}$, it is calculated as:

$f(5)=∑ ^5_{k=1}\frac{1}{k} C^5_k=\frac{2^1-1}{1}+\frac{2^2-1}{2}+\frac{2^3-1}{3}+\frac{2^4-1}{4}+\frac{2^5-1}{5}=\frac{887}{60}$